# java:storing checkbox values to mysql database as zeros(unchecked) and ones(checked) and retrieving it properly to display it to user

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve checkbox values from mysql which I have stored it in the form of 1's(checked) and 0's(unchecked), but I have no idea how to retrieve it.or else is there any other options available for the same

Here is my jsp and servlet code:

**HobbiesTest.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="HobbiesTestServlet" method="post">

            <input type = "checkbox" name = "Hobbies" value = 'Dancing' >Dancing
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "Hobbies" value = 'Reading'>Reading         
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "Hobbies" value = 'Singing'  >Singing
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "Hobbies" value = 'Programming'>Programming
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "Hobbies" value = 'Sleeping'>Sleeping

            <input type = "submit" value = 'Submit'>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HobbiesTestServlet.java**

```
package com.fulcrum.EmpForm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class HobbiesTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public HobbiesTestServlet() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            int danceCheck = 0;

            int singCheck = 0;

            int readCheck = 0;

            int programCheck = 0;

            int sleepCheck = 0;

            List<String> hobbiesList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

            String[] hobbies = request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
            if(hobbies != null){
                for(int i=0;i<hobbies.length;i++){
                    System.out.println("hobbies are"+hobbies[i]);
                    hobbiesList.add(hobbies[i]);
                }
            }

            if(hobbiesList.contains("Dancing")){

                danceCheck = 1;

            }

            if(hobbiesList.contains("Reading")){

                readCheck = 1;

            }

            if(hobbiesList.contains("Singing")){

                singCheck = 1;

            }

            if(hobbiesList.contains("Programming")){

                programCheck = 1;

            }

            if(hobbiesList.contains("Sleeping")){

                sleepCheck = 1;

            }
            System.out.println(danceCheck);
            System.out.println(readCheck);
            System.out.println(singCheck);
            System.out.println(programCheck);
            System.out.println(sleepCheck);
        }

    }
```

My database has columns like dance, read, sing, program, sleep,...
Here I have not included database insert code but I know it will work..
Just wanted to know how to retrieve those column names from database whose values are one and display it to user in a jsp page.

Comment: In summary, you want to get the structure of your table, don't you?

Comment: no..i would be adding more columns to this table like first_name,last_name etc..but at the end i want to show all the user entered values in a jsp file..firstly now just working on these checkboxes.. so here the output at the end should be this(your hobbies are : dancing,reading etc.)

Comment: Sp the number of columns of your table -in the output- are customized, dependend of the selected checkbox?